# enabling anonymous users to Sharepoint 2013 - your opinion please

Tags: sharepoint-2013, anonymous-users

Problem with enabling anonymous users to **SharePoint 2013**

I am trying to enable anonymous users to access the site or maybe some pages on the site and I have made the regular steps, but still it is not working.

I have enabled anonymous on the web application.

Site settings -> Permission settings -> Anonymous Access -> Entire web site and also I've stopped the inheritance for the site

After that it's still not working on the server but it works with me on *LocalHost* but not work with me on the server!.

any help please?

What else do I need to do?

Comment: You should really be asking this on [sharepoint.se]

Answer (score 0):

Try publishing everything,
master pages
page layouts
css
all pages.

I don't understand why you have stopped Inheritance of permissions, also is there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Don't stop inheriting the permission from the parent site and try it. After hosting it in public check the same settings of the site